# Al acceder a una posición del array me muestra otro valor diferente al que inicialice

Tags: javascript

No me devuelve el valor correcto almacenado en un arreglo, me devuelve una cifra diferente.

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```js
const POSITIONS = [12434, 02461];
    
console.log(POSITIONS[0]); // 12434
console.log(POSITIONS[1]); // me devuelve 1329, quiero que me devuelva 02461
```

Comment: tu numero empieza con `0` el cual es ignorado y luego empiezan los problemas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible mantener el cero inicial, a menos que declares el valor como cadena, de otra forma, Javascript tratará de interpretar el valor, ya sea entero (eliminado el cero) o como alguna otra representación numérica (octal, hexadecimal, etc.).

```js
const POSITIONS = [12434, 02461];

console.log(POSITIONS[0]); // 12434
console.log(POSITIONS[1]); // me devuelve 1329, quiero que me devuelva 02461

const POSITIONS2 = [12434, '02461'];

console.log(POSITIONS2[0]); // 12434
console.log(POSITIONS2[1]); // Es cadena, no hay modificación
```